# Getting the content of an xml file creates an XML Parsing Error

Tags: php, xml, http-headers

I am trying to get the contents of an XML file in case that the file exists or I am generating a new xml file. The problem is that when I am trying to get the xml file I get this error:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   http://mydomain.gr/generate.php Line Number 1, Column 1: ^

My code is this

```
<?php

include_once('xmlgenerator.php');
$xml = new XmlGenerator();
if($xml->cachefile_exists){
    if(!$xml->is_uptodate()){
        // echo "update it now";
        $xml->createFile = 1;
        $data = $xml->create();
        Header('Content-type: text/xml');
        print($data->asXML());
    }else{
        //echo "doesn't need any update.";
        Header('Content-type: text/xml');
        file_get_contents($xml->cached_file);
    }
}else{
   // echo "Didn't find any cache file. Lets Create it";
        $xml->createFile = 1;
        $data = $xml->create();
        Header('Content-type: text/xml');
        print($data->asXML());
}
?>
```

The XML structure is fine, and I double check about the XML file encoding or the php file that call the XML. Everything is UTF8 without BOM. When I open the XML file directly in a browsers it looks perfect and its a valid file ( checked it with w3c and online tools).

the 2 lines that create the problem(most probably):

```
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
file_get_contents($xml->cached_file)
```

I even deleted anything and just used this 2 lines and got the same error.

So what can be wrong? Is there any proper way to include an XML file in a php file, change the headers and show it to the end user? I really don't want to redirect, I need to stay to the same php file just show XML content.

Comment: Can I see the source of this `xmlgenerator.php` that you are using?

Comment: Its huge and has nothing to do with the problem. As I told, even if you delete everything and you just call the XML file, the error is exactly the same. If you are just curious I can send you the code I have uploaded it to github.

Comment: Can you try deleting everything, keeping only the header code and use `file_get_content` with http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115? If the error still occurs, it's a server configuration problem. Maybe a proxy problem.

Comment: Even with the yahoo's xml I get the same error. I am under my dev pc (localhost)so I am pretty sure its not a proxy issue. Maybe a php/apache issue then?

Comment: Shouldn't you put an echo before the file_get_contents?

Comment: Shit.. I am very so embarrassed. The forgotten echo was the issue. Can't be more Damp than this. I am really sorry for your time...

Comment: oh boy... And I didn't see it either. I was about to suggest you post the content when you fetch the yahoo link with curl() :D

Comment: Is there anyway that I can delete this question? Matthew can keep his credit of course.... What a stupid moment. The project is here Lim https://github.com/lollypopgr/virtuemart-skroutz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo file_get_contents($xml->cached_file)
```